# New Ubuntu server with Virtual Host show directory instead of website

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I'm setting up a new Ubuntu 16.04 server with Apache. I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04/) to do my setup.

Now when I try to access the site it shows me an empty directory. If I try to access a specific file (index.html) the server doesn't find it. Even trying to see the default website (by accessing my public IP) I get an empty directory.

Here's my .conf file:

```
ServerAdmin admin@website.com
ServerName website.com
ServerAlias www.website.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/website.com/public_html

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

(for the purpose of this public question I changed the name of the site for website.com)

All file's and folder's rights are set to my username as owner and www-data as group. Apache's error log shows nothing wrong and access log is empty.

I banged my head for hours on this issue without any progress so any help is welcome!

Thanks

P.S.: The server is Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS 64b running on a VirtualBox VM.

Answer (score 0):

Obiviously you have missed out something. Please check that you have

> /var/www/example.com/public_html/index.html

with correct spellings.

Also make sure that the config has both index.html and index.php in DirectoryIndex, [check this link for more info](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html)

If all is correct create a .htaccess file in /var/www/example.com/public_html/

> nano /var/www/example.com/public_html/.htaccess file

and then add the followings in it.

> DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.php

Comment: I made some more testing and found that the problem is not what I expected!  The problem is some kind of instability from Apache.  What I mean is that it serves the pages from time to time but most of the time it doesn't.  I accessed my public IP then saw the Default page then did  a refresh 2-3 minutes later and I get an empty folder listing. At some point I can do another refresh and get the page once in a while.  I tried on two new servers setup and got the same thing.

Comment: this problem is beyond my scope.

Comment: After more investigating it looks likes it's network related. I think it have to do with some network stability issue in VBox with bridged network adapter. I'll do some testing and post my answer here.